# SVG can't be scaled with CSS

Tags: css, svg, scaling

I'm encountering a problem with scaling an SVG document. It's included in an HTML document:

```svg
<svg class="svg_class">
    <path class="path_class"     
             d="M 403...
             ... 
             ...z"/>
</svg>
```

I tried to scale it with CSS, as follows:

```css
svg.svg_class {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
}
```

… to no avail. I also tried using `px` units, but that doesn't work either.

I can make it work using `transform: scale(0.1);`, but is there another way to solve this, e.g. when specifying dimensions in attributes as with `img` elements?

Comment: Can you throw a demo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T3sn2/embedded/result/

Comment: that's how it looks on my page

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/T3sn2/1/ >>

Comment: thanks... but it still looks like "overflow: hidden"

Comment: made it work with "transform: scale(0.1);" on the path

Comment: Oh so you wanted that, anyways, nice you solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `viewBox` attribute on the `svg` element, it's designed for that purpose. In conjunction with `preserveAspectRatio` it grants full control over scaling the SVG canvas.

#### Further reading

- [Making sense of SVG viewBox's madness](http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Making+Sense+of+SVG+viewBox%27s+Madness) by *Justin MacCandless*

#### References

- [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)
- [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

Comment: This answer just hits the bull's eye ;-)

Comment: huh :) glad to have helped, @JohnJohnson.

Answer (score 1):

Look at www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html, section 6.16 User agent style sheet. You apparently need to give `height="xxx"` in the `<svg>` tag, or for CSS use `attr()`.

Comment: thanks... but the svg acts like a container... I can change the height, but the height of the content stays the same, acts like with "overflow: hidden"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill the browser screen fully with your svg...

An SVG Image fills the screen when: The body `style="overflow:hidden"`. It is included in a DIV (`style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;"`). Sets the SVG width/height to **window.innerWidth/innerHeight** The svg **viewBox** attribute is set to the bounding box values of the svg image.

Try this example:

```xml
<body style='overflow:hidden;background-color:red'>
    <div id="svgDiv" style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
        <svg id="mySVG">
            <circle id="myCircle" cx="120" cy="180" r="40" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
            <rect id="myRect" x="220" y="250" width="60" height="60" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
            <ellipse id="myEllipse1" cx="900" cy="1200" rx="150" ry="75" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
            <ellipse id="myEllipse2" cx="1900" cy="90" rx="150" ry="75" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
            <ellipse id="myEllipse3" cx="3900" cy="2200" rx="150" ry="75" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Then fire the function onload:

```js
function sizeFull() {
    var svgW=window.innerWidth
    var svgH=window.innerHeight
    var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height
    mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",bbx+" "+bby+" "+bbw+" "+bbh )
    mySVG.setAttribute("width",svgW)
    mySVG.setAttribute("height",svgH)
}
document.addEventListener("onload",sizeFull(),false)
```